# How to check for a M2M match or None with django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models both with a M2M field pointing to the same third model:

```
class Moo(models.Model):
    ...

class Foo(models.Model):
    moos = models.ManyToManyField(Moo, blank=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    moos = models.ManyToManyField(Moo)
```

I need to find all 'Foo' objects that either have no 'manytomany' objects selected, or at least one manytomany objects that match an individual 'Bar' object.

So my data might look like this:

```
foo1.moos__all = 'boo', 'yah'
foo2.moos__all = <none>
foo3.moos__all = 'suck'

bar1.moos__all = 'boo'
```

Then doing this search would produce:

```
bar1.find_matches()
>>> foo1, foo2
```

The data model used to **have** to include at least one item match, so was easy as:

```
Foo.objects.filter(manytomany__in=bar1.moos.all())
```

Now the model has changed, and Foo.moos can be blank. So in short, I need to do this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(
    Q(moos__in=bar1.moos.all()) | Q(moos__count=0)
)
```

Sadly `__count` is not an option :(

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following not work?

```
Foo.objects.filter(
    Q(moos__in=bar1.moos.all()) | Q(moos=None)
)
```

Comment: That does it! It did point out some more issues I've got with the data model migration which negates the need for this extra filter anyway, but useful to know. Simple things!